# Controlling the mouse from perl in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, perl

Is here any way control mouse movements and clicks in OS X from perl?
Found several python solutions, but not perl - yet.

If here isn't perl solution, is possible call python (or ruby) code from perl (not mean via fork/exec/system) but like "Inline::Lua" or soo..

thanx.

Comment: There is for Windows -  [`Win32::GuiTest`](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest-1.60/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm). Not sure of a module that supports `darwin` architecture.

Comment: Are you trying to control any specific applications, or the mouse pointer in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I'd suggest you use Python and [ATOMac](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/atomac).  There is [Inline::Python](http://search.cpan.org/~nine/Inline-Python/) but I have not used it; it looks pretty mature though.